# Function to count vowels in a string

Tags: ruby

Why isnt this working?

```
def count_vowels(string)
  result = 0
  i = 0
  while i < string.length
    if string[i] == "a" ||"e" || "i" || "o" || "u"
      result = result + 1
      i += 1
    end
    return result
  end
```

Comment: why the negative votes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you have a `end` missing for your `if`. I think you wanted to do this (which will not give you the correct answer though):

```
def count_vowels(string)
    result = 0
    i = 0
    while i < string.length
        if string[i] == "a" ||"e" || "i" || "o" || "u"
            result = result + 1
            i += 1
        end
    end

    return result
end
```

Try doing this using a regular expression like this:

```
def count_vowels(string)
  string.scan(/[aeouiAEIOU]/).count
end
```

`/[aeouiAEIOU]/` is a regular expression that basically means any of these characters: `a, e, o, u, i, A, E, I, O, U`.

The [String#scan](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-scan) method returns all matches of that regular expression in the string which means you get the number of vowels!

Comment: I am missing the end. Thanks for pointing that out. But this function does not work

Answer (score 3):

It does not work because it will always be true. 
Your current expression is evaluated as (in words) does this letter equal a? if this is false then "e" it does not evaluate the first letter equaling "e" it simply evaluated to "e". As an if statement it is equivalent to:

```
if string[i] == "a"
  result += 1
  i += 1
else 
  "e"
  result += 1
  i += 1
end
```

Try this

```
%w(a e i o u).include?(string[i])
```

That being said it would be easier to do

```
string.scan(/[aeiou]/i).count
```

and then you need not loop at all

Comment: ...or `string.count 'aeiouAEIOU'` (or maybe that should be `'aeiouAEIOUandsomtimesyY'`).

Comment: @CarySwoveland you are correct (excepting the cheeky second part) although I would prefer the regex or `string.downcase.count("aeiou")` because I don't like the need to type both cases

Answer (score 1):

First of all, unless you are using the postfix version of `if`, it should be enclosed by `end`. Aka:

```
if condition
  action
end
```

Second of all, what

```
string[i] == "a" ||"e" || "i" || "o" || "u"
```

translates to is: `string[i] == "a"` or `"e"` or `"i"` or `"o"` or `"u"`. In Ruby, `nil` and `false` are considered *falsey* values, everything else is *truthy*.

What you really meant here is

```
if ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o',' u'].include? string[i]
  result += 1
end
```

---

However, this code as of right now is very *C* like. Ruby offers way better level of abstraction for such tasks. I would suggest looking into [String methods](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-count) to find a simpler solution.

Answer (score 0):

Just saw all the solutions. I'm sure some of them work as well as the one I figured out. One of the problems as suggested in some answers was that I was missing the end on my if statement. This is what I did:

```
def count_vowels(string)
    result = 0

    i = 0
    while i < string.length
        if (string[i] == "a" || string[i] == "e" || string[i] == "i" || string[i] == "o" || string[i] == "u")
        result = result + 1

        end
    i += 1
    end

    return result

end
```

Comment: If you intended to solve your own problem and post it as an answer while ignoring more idiomatic and simpler solutions why then did you ask the question? Also a few more notes 1) there is almost always a better way to loop in ruby than using `for`, `while`, `until`, etc. loops (see [`String#chars`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-chars)) 2) result = result + 1 can be result += 1 just like you did with i.

Comment: I was not being able to solve it myself. And I would have still struggled to understand why  doing (string[i] == "a" || string[i] == "e" || string[i] == "i" || string[i] == "o" || string[i] == "u") is different from doing string[i] == "a" ||"e" || "i" || "o" || "u". You all helped me understand it.